# C3P0 Connection Pool initialPoolSize not working with AWS Athena

Tags: jdbc, amazon-athena, mulesoft, c3p0

**Context**:
I am accessing AWS Athena DB using Simba JDBC Driver with C3P0 connection pooling (CP) configured. Encountering DB Connection Pooling threads being reinitialized after some time, even though have configured various C3P0 fine tuning properties. Please find list of them below:

```
C3P0 Version: c3p0-0.9.5.5 \[built 11-December-2019 22:18:33 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10\]
maxWait: "20"
maxStatements: "10"
maxPoolSize: "20"
minPoolSize: "3"
maxIdleTime: "1800"
preparedStatementCacheSize: "5"
acquireIncrement: "3"
idleConnectionTestPeriod: "30"
initialPoolSize: "3"  
testConnectionOnCheckin: "true"
testConnectionOnCheckout: "false"
debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces: "true"
```

App Deployed on 2 workers with multiple (>1) worker threads.

**Issues & Questions:**

1. `initialPoolSize` is not working at all. At max, pool size is at most 1 connection per worker.

- Even after C3P0 pool is stable (with "Refurbishing idle resources" logs appearing in logs frequently)
- Once DB request is initiated, CP thread is re-initialized as new (Log Sample 1: Initializing c3p0 pool...)

2. Another Observation is there seem to be multiple CP objects simultaneously in same worker. Could this correspond to worker threads? Why do they exist simultaneously? (Log Sample 2: BasicResourcePool@52e8fb44 & BasicResourcePool@6383620e)

**Log Sample 1**: Sample Logs from 1 worker (not necessarily for same DB Connection Pool thread):

[2023-10-22 12:01:54.067] WARN  Attempted to override property initialPoolSize using additional-properties. Proceeding to use initialPoolSize = 3.

[2023-10-22 12:01:54.235] INFO Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@233ef5fb [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@39b1da15 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 20000, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken -> rvmyeoazo7l0pbm9pc6k|4201cfe6, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 30, initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 10, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 5, minPoolSize -> 3, nestedDataSource -> StandardDataSource:

[2023-10-22 12:01:55.788] DEBUG  acquire test -- pool size: 1; target_pool_size: 6; desired target? 4

[2023-10-22 12:01:55.783] DEBUG awaitAvailable():

[2023-10-22 12:01:56.460] DEBUG ResultSet opened, now 1 active
[2023-10-22 12:01:56.595] DEBUG  Closing 1 resultSets

---

**Log Sample 2**: Logs for multiple CP Objects in question 2:

[2023-10-22 07:52:49.552] DEBUG   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->rvn2r2aznyqbureaga4x|6c762ebf]-AdminTaskTimer]: Refurbishing idle resources - Sun Oct 22 07:52:49 UTC 2023 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@52e8fb44]

[2023-10-22 08:01:04.771] DEBUG   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->rvn2r2aznyqbureaga4x|26020260]-AdminTaskTimer]: Refurbishing idle resources - Sun Oct 22 08:01:04 UTC 2023 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6383620e]

[2023-10-22 08:13:34.773] DEBUG   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->rvn2r2aznyqbureaga4x|26020260]-AdminTaskTimer]: Refurbishing idle resources - Sun Oct 22 08:13:34 UTC 2023 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6383620e]

[2023-10-22 09:12:49.578] DEBUG   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->rvn2r2aznyqbureaga4x|6c762ebf]-AdminTaskTimer]: Refurbishing idle resources - Sun Oct 22 09:12:49 UTC 2023 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@52e8fb44]

---

Mule DB Connector: v1.14.4

Mule DB Connection Config: Generic Connection

Mule Runtime: v4.4.0 EE (Latest Patch)

Deployment: CloudHub 1.0

Worker Config: 0.2 vCore with 2 workers

Athena Simba JDBC Jar: v2.0.36.1000

---

[Edit-2]

```
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config"
    doc:id="2a143827-dd45-4f32-a555-a24df53b0264">
    <db:generic-connection
        url="#[vars.athenaConnectionUrl.url]"
        driverClassName="com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver" user="#[vars.athenaVaultVar.Athena.username]"
        password="#[vars.athenaVaultVar.Athena.password]" >
        <db:pooling-profile minPoolSize="${athena.db.minPoolSize}" testConnectionOnCheckout="false" maxPoolSize="${athena.db.maxPoolSize}" acquireIncrement="${athena.db.pooling.acquire.increment}" preparedStatementCacheSize="${athena.db.pooling.cache.size}" maxWait="${athena.db.connectionWaitTimeout}" maxIdleTime="${athena.db.standard.idleTimeout}" maxStatements="${athena.db.maxStatement}">
            <db:additional-properties >
                <db:additional-property key="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${athena.db.pooling.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
                <db:additional-property key="initialPoolSize" value="${athena.db.pooling.initialPoolSize}" />
                <db:additional-property key="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${athena.db.pooling.testConnectionOnCheckin}" />
                <db:additional-property key="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${athena.db.pooling.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces}" />
            </db:additional-properties>
        </db:pooling-profile>
    </db:generic-connection>
</db:config>
```

[/Edit-2]

Comment: Hi @steve-waldman,
Possible to look into this?

Comment: What is the relationship with MuleSoft?

Comment: You shouldn't make multiple questions in one. Make separate questions.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your issue is? `initialPoolSize` is just the initial target the pool builds to, after initialization, before any activity that might build the pool towards `maxPoolSize` or bring down the pool towards `minPoolSize`. It's at best a very fragile parameter, because lots of things begin to push the pool size up and down. Are you somehow trying to rely upon it? What is actually giving you trouble?

Comment: Hi @SteveWaldman,
The issue I am facing is in Connection Pool, there is never more than 1 thread ever (even at start-up or later). Either `pool size: 0;` or `pool size: 1; `
There are never more than 1 CP threads as per logs. This means, whenever DB request is made, `Log Sample 1: Initializing c3p0 pool...` CP initialization occurs which takes ~ 5-6 secs to initialize. I would like to avoid this at all costs.

Comment: Hi @aled,
1. Code is written using mulesoft DB Connector. Which means code is well tested since I haven't written custom code except all DB configuration bits.

Comment: Then please add the Database Connector configurations andnMule and connector versions for reference.

Comment: Hi @aled,
Added relevant Mulesoft details.

Comment: Please add the XML configuration for the Database connector, as text.

Comment: Hi @aled, Added it now.

Comment: @SourabhLonikar If you are seeing "Initializing c3p0 pool..." on every request, that means you are creating the pool in the path of client requests. c3p0 `Connection` pools should be a shared, long-lived object. It will do the opposite of any good if you construct them once per request. I don't know anything about the middleware you are using, but usually you want the pool as a long-lived `static`, or an application-scoped item in old-school J2EE webapps, or whatever long-lived scope exosts in your framework.

Comment: Hi @SteveWaldman, 

I understood your point. You mean to say that, code should create CP as one-time activity and use CP threads as and when required. That is what is happening, because "Initializing c3p0 pool..." is **not** happening on every request, but happens frequently enough to be an issue. Another issue seems to be that DB pool size never exceeds 1!

Comment: Hi @SteveWaldman 
I am looking into possibility of maybe AthenaDB is not itself an Database, even though it acts as a Database (SQL) and I can connect using SQL Workbench/J and Mulesoft DB Connector with AWS provided Simba JDBC Driver. Reason being while traditional AWS DB have page like this [1] (which provided `max_connections` property), no such page exists for AWS Athena except this [2] which lists 20 Concurrent Athena Requests limitation.

Do you have any reference where C3P0 was/is used to connect with AWS Athena ?

Comment: References for above comment:

[1]:  [AWS RDBMS `MaxConnections`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections)

[2]: [AWS Athena Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/athena.html#amazon-athena-limits)

Comment: Supporting AWS Athena is not a traditional DB, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_jdbc.html#retrieving-secrets_jdbc_example_c3p0_replica) AWS user-guide list every major RDBMS except AWS Athena.

Comment: @SourabhLonikar I know very little about AWS Athena. If you can connect to it via JDBC, you can probably pool Connections to it with c3p0 (unless it doesn't support the full JDBC api). Whether c3p0 is a good choice for it, I don't know.

Comment: @SourabhLonikar for a well structured application, you should only see "Initializing c3p0 pool..." basically once, at application startup (or if you are hot-reloading, on restarts of the application). c3p0 connection pools are singleton resources whose lifespan is usually the lifespan of the application that contains them. There are some unusual exceptions (e.g. applications that work with multiple databases over different time intervals), but they are, well, unusual.

Comment: Hi @SteveWaldman,
As per [AWS Athena Simba JDBC Driver Documentation](https://downloads.athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.1.1.1000/docs/Simba+Amazon+Athena+JDBC+Connector+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf) (Page 14: "Registering the Connector Class"), It seems Connection Pooling will be supported only in DataSource class in DB Config. I think current JDBC driver class (`java.sql.Driver`) does not support CP. We may need to migrate to DataSource (`javax.sql.DataSource`) method for CP benefit.